# How can I publish an ebook online?

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, publishing

How can I publish e-books online so that I can sell them to readers?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. You could always look into something like https://leanpub.com/

Comment: Smashwords.com is a site which lets you sell ebooks on many different bookstores. If you can format the book yourself, you have a lot more options, but you can pay a third party service to do it.

Comment: Of course, you only intend to sell original content for which you have all the rights, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am the author.

Comment: Why do you specify the tag *pdf*, but not *epub* or *mobi*. Is it intentional ? It gives me the impression that your first problem is a technical one: what formats to use, and what type of ereaders to aim for.